# "Fixing 'jupyter' Command Not Found Error in Command Line"

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I have open command prompt and run command

`jupyter notebook`

Jupyter notebook is installed but after run code is:

`'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

I will trying to run command:

`pip install jupyterlab`

And successfuly installed jupyterlab,

After run command

`jupyter notebook`

I will expecting to successfuly open browser in jupyter but It was can't worked.

And problem faceing to,

`'jupyter' is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file.`

Answer (score 0):

Pip install jupyter and other executable scripts to `$HOME/.local/bin` (in Windows, `$HOME` is `C:\Users\<username>` by default).

To execute anything there, you must add the directory to `PATH` environment variable. If you haven't done that, `pip install jupyter` will end with warnings, containing the path to add to PATH.

For how to add PATH, check [How do I edit my system path in Windows?](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/94933-how-do-i-edit-my-system-path-in-windows)